# How to convert JSON Array to Single JSON String?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function which returns me the following string

```
[{"email":"test@gmail.com"},{"password":"test"}]
```

and I want to convert it to this

```
{"email":"test@gmail.com","password":"test*"}
```

This is the code I'm currently using.

```
var obj = $.map(inputs, function (x, y) {
    var ret = {};
    ret[x.name] = $(x).val();
    return ret;
});

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Can you please add the code which returns that output?

Comment: `var obj = $.extend({},json1,json2);
console.log(obj);` try from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: added the code snippet i am using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   var inputs = [{"email":"test@gmail.com"},{"password":"test"}];

   var obj = {};

   $.each(inputs, function(index, item) {
     $.extend(obj, item);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
var obj = {}

$.map(inputs, function (x, y) {
   obj [x.name] = $(x).val();
});
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

## Why your code isn't working the way you want to?

```
var obj = $.map(inputs, function (x, y) {
    var ret = {};
    ret[x.name] = $(x).val();
    return ret;
});
```

Simply because you are creating a new object `var ret = {};` every time and setting only one value to it and then push it into an array `ret[x.name] = $(x).val();`. This array then you are returning `return ret;` which becomes part of your `obj`.

So, your object `obj` is basically an array of objects `ret` which has only one key `x.name` and value `$(x).val()`.

By changing your code to the one I have given you will be able to get an object (which you intend to achieve) instead on an array (which you want to transform into an object).

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this and not what the Asker tried...

Comment: @JohnHascall made the changes to explain why OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @ssk I have explained why your code isn't working the way you want to. Have a look, hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
var obj = {};

$('input').each(function(){
   obj[this.type] = this.value
});

$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='email' value='test@test.com'><br>
<input type='password' value='123456'><br>


<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receives a string, just do it:

```
var myNewJson =  JSON.parse(your_string);
```

But, I saw you are converting an array of object in a unique object. Is it you want? You can use .reduce(). More info here [Array.prototype.reduce()](http:////developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)